# Progressbar loading delay on SplashScreen page in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, progress-bar, splash-screen

In my app, have long running process in background before loading the app. So that i developed splashscreen with progressbar in popup. Popup is open and closed is workign well. It doest not give any problem. But progressbar in splashscreen, not loaded quickly when popup opened, some second delay happend. Progressbar always in visible mode and Isdeterminate also true mode.

I don't know why delay happend for progressbar.

This problem happend only in windows phone 7.1 only.

Pls Help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you try to draw the same `Splash Screen` image but with `Progress Bar` on top after application has been launched. Probably, your hard loading work performed on `UI thread`, so it freeze `Progress Bar` also. Try to move all work to background thread and if you have complex layouts (in `ListBox`, for example), try to add items with some delay to give `UI thread` time to update anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The splashcreen is shown whilst the phone unpacks the .XAP file, loads the assemblies, starts the Silverlight runtime and renders your first page. Until this happens, you application is not executing, so you cannot display a progress bar or perform any other tasks. Hence the delay.

The only think you can do is work to reduce the XAP size and make your initial UI as simple as possible so that the first page renders quickly.